# Animated side-menu in 2 rollover sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code and wanted to know if there is a possibility split the menu list in two rollover sections, like we have in this [example](http://goo.gl/ZHKBu0) activated by **next** and **previous** buttons.

I've been trying to figure out how the `pagination` code section works but unfortunately I'm not good enough in order to adapt and achieve a good result on my existing snippet.

I would greatly appreciate to have your code solution and thoughts. Thanks

```
<div class="pagination" id="pagination"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changePage(2,19, true)" class="next_page">Next page</a>&nbsp;<span>(1 of 2)</span></div>
```

```css
body {
    font: normal 1.0em Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #A8CBFF;
}

nav {
    font-size: 3.0em;
    line-height: 1.0em;
    color: white;
    
    width:6em;
    height: 9.0em;

    position:absolute;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    left: -4.5em;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 1.0em;
    padding: 0.25em;
    position: relative;

    border-top-right-radius: 0.75em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.75em;

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms, background-color 500ms, color 500ms;
    transition: transform 500ms, background-color 500ms, color 500ms;
}

nav ul li:nth-child(1) { background-color: #00aced;}
nav ul li:nth-child(2) { background-color: #3b5998;}
nav ul li:nth-child(3) { background-color: #517fa4;}
nav ul li:nth-child(4) { background-color: #007bb6;}
nav ul li:nth-child(5) { background-color: #cb2027;}
nav ul li:nth-child(6) { background-color: #ea4c89;}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #C1232D;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(4.5em);
    transform: translateX(4.5em);
}

nav ul li span {
    display:block;
    font-family: Arial;
    position: absolute;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    height:1.0em;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    right: 0.16666666666667em;
    color: #F8F6FF;
}

a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com">Category 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">Category 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com">Category 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com">Category 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com">Category 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com">Category 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Few questions before I attempt to solve this: 1. Which links would you want on *page 1*, and which ones on *page 2*? 2. Would this be a static amount of pages, or could there be more than two pages?

Comment: Hey there and thank you for your interest. Actually you can build your code taking in consideration 2-3 generic links on the first section of the menu and also 2-3 generic links on the second menu section. Sorry for misundrstanding. Please note, I don't think that changing the menu will change also a page (pages are changed when the menu links are accessed). The let's say "rollover" next/ previous effect it happens on the same page of the site, just wanted to be clear. Also hope that the live site [example](http://goo.gl/ZHKBu0) can "tell" you how this can be build.

Comment: I've edited the subject to avoid any misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if there is a possibility split the menu list in two rollover
>   sections, like we have in this example activated by next and previous
>   buttons

In order to do this **dynamically**, you need to first draw up an algorithm. Here is a rough idea:

1. Think of a page size that you wish to have,
2. Count the number of links in your mark-up,
3. Arrive at the required number of pages based on the page size and count of links,
4. Use a counter to keep track of the current page,
5. Show the current page by hiding the all links before and after the current page,
6. show/hide navigation buttons based on the current page, and lastly
7. Handle click of prev/next button to show previous/next pages.

Now try to implement this algorithm in your code step by step. Here is a very very crude example (*I am not duplicating the styling as you already have that*):

For the first four, you can use variables like this (*explanation in code comments*):

```
var pageSize = 5,                           // configurable page size
    $links = $("#pagedMenu li"),            // select your links
    count = $links.length,                  // count of your links
    numPages = Math.ceil(count / pageSize), // number of pages required
    curPage = 1                             // start current page at 1
;
```

To show the current page, first show all links and then hide all the links before and after the current page. You can do this by using the index in the cached list of jQuery objects in the variable `$links` above, like this (*explanation in code comments*):

```
function showPage(whichPage) { // function to show a particular page
    // previous links are the ones before where the current page starts
    // for example, if current page is 2, and each page has 5 links
    // then previous links are before index 5. 
    // (1st page indices are 0 thru 4.
    var previousLinks = (whichPage - 1) * pageSize, 

        // next links are after all previous links calculated above,
        // plus the page size. for example, if current page is 2, 
        // previous links are before index 5, add page size of 5,
        // so remaining links start at index 10.
        nextLinks = (previousLinks + pageSize);

    $links.show(); // show all links

    // slice the list from 0 thru previousLinks index calculated above
    // and hide them
    $links.slice(0, previousLinks).hide();

    // slice the list from nextLinks index calculated above and hide them
    $links.slice(nextLinks).hide();

    showPrevNext(); // call function to show/hide navigation buttons
}
```

To show/hide the next/previous navigation links, now all you have to do is to check (1) if current page is first page, then only show next button, (2) if current page is last page, then only show previous button, (3) otherwise show both buttons. You can also show the page numbers easily. Here is a rough exmaple:

```
function showPrevNext() {
    if ((numPages > 0) && (curPage < numPages)) {
        $("#nextPage").removeClass('hidden'); 
        $("#msg").text("(" + curPage + " of " + numPages + ")");
    } else { 
        $("#nextPage").addClass('hidden'); 
    }
    if ((numPages > 0) && (curPage > 1)) {
        $("#prevPage").removeClass('hidden'); 
        $("#msg").text("(" + curPage + " of " + numPages + ")");
    } else { 
        $("#prevPage").addClass('hidden'); 
    }
}
```

Finally, wire up the `click` event on the previous/next buttons of navigation to show previous or next page based on the current page, by calling the `showPage` function that you created above. It will look like this:

```
$("#nextPage").on("click", function() { showPage(++curPage); });
$("#prevPage").on("click", function() { showPage(--curPage); });
```

Also, fire the `showPage` function at the start to start showing from a particular page.

You can see the crude working example in the snippet below. Try changing the `pageSize`. Also, try adding / removing the links in the mark-up.

**Combining all together, an example snippet**:

```js
var pageSize = 5, 
    $links = $("#pagedMenu li"), 
    count = $links.length, 
    numPages = Math.ceil(count / pageSize), 
    curPage = 1
;

showPage(curPage);

function showPage(whichPage) {
    var previousLinks = (whichPage - 1) * pageSize, 
        nextLinks = (previousLinks + pageSize);
    $links.show();
    $links.slice(0, previousLinks).hide();
    $links.slice(nextLinks).hide();
    showPrevNext();
}

function showPrevNext() {
    if ((numPages > 0) && (curPage < numPages)) {
        $("#nextPage").removeClass('hidden'); 
        $("#msg").text("(" + curPage + " of " + numPages + ")");
    } else { 
        $("#nextPage").addClass('hidden'); 
    }
    if ((numPages > 0) && (curPage > 1)) {
        $("#prevPage").removeClass('hidden'); 
        $("#msg").text("(" + curPage + " of " + numPages + ")");
    } else { 
        $("#prevPage").addClass('hidden'); 
    }
}

$("#nextPage").on("click", function() { showPage(++curPage); });
$("#prevPage").on("click", function() { showPage(--curPage); });
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="pagedMenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li><li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li><li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li><li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li><li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 9</a></li><li><a href="#">Link 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 11</a></li><li><a href="#">Link 12</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 13</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="pagination">
    <a href="#" id="prevPage" class="hidden">Previous</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="#" id="nextPage" class="hidden">Next</a>
    <span id="msg"></span>
</div>
```

**Fiddle Link**: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/7ntt2964/

Comment: I think that here we have a code battle :D let me analyze this closely. Thank you. Very detailed.

Comment: @typo_78: Not really, there is no code battle. Just another answer on your question. :)

Comment: I was kidding, I agree :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```js
/* Bootstrap minified JavaScript included as External Resource */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#page2').hide();
    $('#paginate_pre').hide();
    
    $('#paginate_next').on('click', function(){
        $('#page1').hide();
        $('#page2').show();        
        $('#paginate_next').hide();
        $('#paginate_pre').show();
    });
        
    $('#paginate_pre').on('click', function(){
        $('#page2').hide();
        $('#page1').show();
        $('#paginate_pre').hide();
        $('#paginate_next').show();        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<nav id="page1">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com">Category 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">Category 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com">Category 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com">Category 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com">Category 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com">Category 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<nav id="page2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com">Category 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">Category 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com">Category 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com">Category 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com">Category 11</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com">Category 12</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div ><a href="#" id="paginate_next">NEXT</a></div>
<div ><a href="#" id="paginate_pre">PREV</a></div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anandgh/ozuzgdnt/

Comment: Thank you but.. your jsfiddle, show another effect (revealing the menu links from top to bottom). Is that your solution or the code is messing around? :) also code snippet doesn't work at all.

Comment: The effects where coming due to show('slow') property. I have removed it. Check it once

Comment: Thank you Anand. As we can see, in my snippet, menu links are animated (as the title said). Can you make this happen? Also can you keep the existing `css` properties or fork my snippet? I'm noob in coding not lazy and don't want to miss something. I appreciate it.

Comment: you should really try and understand how and why things work... somebody else fixing all of your problem will not make you a good programmer!

Comment: I totally agree. just wanted to be sure that everything looks good. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKvprO; @Silent_coder I just put code pieces together till I get the desired result. I swear that I have nothing in common with coding ...I read/ask implement somethimes it's working :)

Comment: I think, I have answered you question very well and as per http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKvprO, it seems like you implemented it. Happy to see that will be more happy if you accept my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class to the menu options that you want to be on "page 1" and a different class to the menu options that you want on "page 2", then show/hide accordingly by changing the class of the nav. Something like this:

```js
$("#next-page").on("click", function() {
  $("nav").removeClass("page1").addClass("page2");
});
$("#previous-page").on("click", function() {
  $("nav").removeClass("page2").addClass("page1");
});
```

```css
nav.page1 .page1-linkk { display:block; }
nav.page1 .page2-link { display:none; }
nav.page2 .page1-link { display:none; }
nav.page2 .page2-link { display:block; }
#next-page, #previous-page { text-align:right; }

body {
    font: normal 1.0em Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #A8CBFF;
}

nav {
    font-size: 3.0em;
    line-height: 1.0em;
    color: white;
    
    width:6em;
    height: 9.0em;

    position:absolute;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    left: -4.5em;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 1.0em;
    padding: 0.25em;
    position: relative;

    border-top-right-radius: 0.75em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.75em;

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms, background-color 500ms, color 500ms;
    transition: transform 500ms, background-color 500ms, color 500ms;
}

nav ul li:nth-child(1) { background-color: #00aced;}
nav ul li:nth-child(2) { background-color: #3b5998;}
nav ul li:nth-child(3) { background-color: #517fa4;}
nav ul li:nth-child(4) { background-color: #007bb6;}
nav ul li:nth-child(5) { background-color: #cb2027;}
nav ul li:nth-child(6) { background-color: #ea4c89;}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #C1232D;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(4.5em);
    transform: translateX(4.5em);
}

nav ul li span {
    display:block;
    font-family: Arial;
    position: absolute;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    height:1.0em;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    right: 0.16666666666667em;
    color: #F8F6FF;
}

a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="page1" id="mynav">
  <ul>
    <li class="page1-link"><a href="http://www.twitter.com">Category 1</a></li>
    <li class="page1-link"><a href="http://www.facebook.com">Category 2</a></li>
    <li class="page1-link"><a href="http://www.instagram.com">Category 3</a></li>
    <li class="page1-link" id="next-page">NEXT</li>
    <li class="page2-link"><a href="http://www.instagram.com">Category 4</a></li>
    <li class="page2-link"><a href="http://www.instagram.com">Category 5</a></li>
    <li class="page2-link"><a href="http://www.instagram.com">Category 6</a></li>
    <li class="page2-link" id="previous-page">PREVIOUS</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you as well Mr. Alvaro, I appreciate it.